# How do I redirect the input and output of a console C# program to a socket?

Tags: c#, sockets, redirect, console

How do I redirect the input and output of a console C# program to a socket? I need to start the program from within another process, and make it receive input and emit output to another process running on another computer in the network. What I'm trying to do is to programmatically run an application on another station, while controlling it from the current terminal.

Comment: `netcat` might help: http://netcat.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class to run your console program.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
```

And then you can hook any stream (including networkstreams) up to `process.StandardInput` and `process.StandardOutput`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll get started on this!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to setup [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput.aspx) and [RedirectStandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx).  This lets you provide a stream to use for standard input/output of the console application.

You can then copy data from the process streams to and from the socket's stream.

Answer (score 0):

Why redirect?

If this is core functionality of your application, then you should have `Stream` variables that your code uses rather than relying on `Console.Out`, etc.

The stream can be opened from a socket, a file, whatever right in code.

Comment: The applications I'll be executing are not written by me and they must also work when launched from their home-station in the console.